# Выражение "закипела кровь"

Tags: идиомы, идиоматика

Здравствуйте.  Можно ли использовать выражение "закипела кровь" по отношению к ситуации, когда на пальце есть рана и она покрылась слоем крови, засохла таким образом? В контексте закипела кровь на пальце.

Comment: @Avatar64, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Не думаю.

В Вашем случае кровь ЗАПЕКЛАСЬ, а не закипела. Закипела кровь-стала горячей = состояние сильного возбуждения, страсть. Фразеологизм - образное выражение, а у Вас прямое.